# Структуры в C# и ее плюсы

Tags: c#, классы, структуры

Где можно использовать структуры? И в каких ситуациях лучше прибегнуть к структурам, нежели к классам?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вольный перевод кусочка [отсюда](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-struct)

> struct is a value type, so it is faster than a class object. Use
> struct whenever you want to just store the data. Generally, structs
> are good for game programming. However, it is easier to transfer a
> class object than a struct. So do not use struct when you are passing
> data across the wire or to other classes.

struct - это значимый тип, поэтому он быстрее, чем объект класса. Используйте struct всякий раз, когда вы хотите просто хранить данные. Как правило, структуры подходят для программирования игр. Однако легче передать объект класса, чем структуру. Поэтому не используйте структуру при передаче данных по сети или другим классам.

Comment: Позволил себе скорректировать немного перевод: `store` - хранить, `save` - сохранить

Comment: value type - тип значений.  Оним хотят сказать, что обьект при проброске через аргументы копируется полностью, а не ссылкой, так, как если бы структуру передавали в с++ без использования * или &.

Comment: Наверно, нужно еще упомянуть про возможные накладные расходы, связанные с упаковкой/распаковкой.                         
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing#:~:text=Boxing%20is%20the%20process%20of,value%20type%20from%20the%20object.

Comment: Все это да, только вот вопрос Где можно использовать структуры? И в каких ситуациях лучше прибегнуть к структурам, нежели к классам? Я постарался кратко ответить. По остальному документации хватает.

Answer (score 5):

Это довольно интересный вопрос.

С одной стороны, структуры в C# есть. Но они очень похожи на классы: у них тоже есть конструкторы - деструкторы, методы. Не надо заботиться об инициализации полей структур - .NET не забудет это сделать.

Единственная разница, которая приходит в голову - что поля структуры нельзя инициализировать в момент объявления.

И что при создании экземпляра структуры new не нужен, достаточно простого объявления вида

```
    UserIunfo ui;
    ui.Name = "Cat";
```

**Главное отличие** структур от классов - в реализации. Любой экземпляр класса создаётся в "куче" (heap) (потому, что класс - это ссылочная структура данных), а экземпляры структур создаются в стеке, как простые переменные примитивных типов.

Это приводит к тому, что активное создание - освобождение экземпляров классов даст работу garbage collector, а экземпляров структур - нет. В целом, счтруктуры нужны там, где производительность на первом месте, и данных "не очень много".

Некоторые преимущества структур, которые проявлялись в C/C++: можно было напрямую записывать "набор байтов длииной со структуру" в бинарный файл - и это было сохранение значения структуры в файле! безо всяких сериализаций. А потом точно такое же считывание. Или - передача по сети.

В комментариях мне подсказывают, что такие же возможности есть и в C#, но использовать их сложнее, чем в C++.

Если я найду примеры такого использования - я постараюсь дополнить этот ответ.

Comment: это всё в c# есть, просто надо знать как это делать и делается "матюком". Есть ф-ция PtrToStructure и StructureToPtr и несколько других полезный ф-ций из Marshal, Есть бинарная сериализация без возможности выкинуть шапку. Просто всё это делается несколько сложнее чем в с++

Comment: @nick_n_a - спасибо за подсказку, я исправил свой ответ

Comment: Ну еще у структур ест ограничение на конструктор. И на наследование (это причина, почему структуры чуть быстрее, чем классы)

Comment: Деструкторы в структурах, в отличие от деструкторов классов, вещь вообще бесполезная.

Comment: > Деструкторы в структурах, в отличие от деструкторов классов, вещь вообще бесполезная - ну, разве что для подчистки за собой в соответсвии с RAII

Comment: Начиная с с#10 структуру можно инициализировать при объявлении

Answer (score 1):

Есть старый [гайд в документации майкрософт](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct) о том, когда использовать классы, а когда структуры. Там дается достаточное описание классам и структурам, а также разницы между ними.

> Где можно использовать структуры? И в каких ситуациях лучше прибегнуть
> к структурам, нежели к классам?

Резюмирую ответ на ваш вопрос из этой статьи:

Как правило, большинство типов в разрабатываемых фреймворках на C# представлены **классами**. Однако иногда структуры будут более подходящим типом ввиду того, что они относятся к значимым типам (основное преимущество - высокая производительность при правильном использовании).

✔️ ИСПОЛЬЗУЙТЕ структуры вместо класса, если экземпляры типа занимают небольшой размер в памяти, и чаще всего недолговечны или встраиваются в другие объекты.

❌ НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗУЙТЕ структуры, если тип **не обладает всеми нижеперечисленными характеристиками**:

- Логически представляет собой **одно значение**, подобное примитивным
  типам (*int, double* и т.д.);
- Размер экземпляра этого типа занимает **менее 16 байт** в памяти;
- Он должен быть **неизменяемым** (immutable);
- Его **не придется часто упаковывать** ([boxing](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing)).

Comment: "Менее 16 байт" - то есть `decimal` у нас не существует? "Не более 16 байт" будет правильнее. Про неизменяемость тоже неверно. Структуру могут (и часто должны) быть изменяемыми, этот факт просто нужно иметь в виду при передаче по ссылке без модификатора "in"

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, что за модификатор `in`?

Comment: @Grundy, брат `ref`

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, понятно, что-то новое

Comment: @Grundy, да уже достаточно старое :) Решает проблему с дурной привычкой компилятора делать бэкапы структуры там, где это не надо, а также упрощает вызов функций: `A(ref 1)` - нельзя, `A(1)` (заметьте, in даже указывать не надо при вызове) - можно, очень полезно для unmanaged api :)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, ага, я посмотрел уже описание. 7.2 - для меня - считай недавно :):):)

Comment: @Grundy, я на 8.0 сижу с самого его выхода хД Так что для меня 7.2 - это давно и неправда

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, еще не все нововведения посмотрел :)

Comment: @Grundy, ну, у Вас это и не основной язык вроде, так что простительно :)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, скорее не самый основной :-D

Comment: @Grundy, а какой, кстати, "самый основной"?)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, там несколько :)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov много воды утекло с момента написания данной статьи на msdn (12 лет назад, как-никак) :).

Comment: Так кто ж спорит, но вы-то дали ответ 3 часа назад, а не 12 лет назад :)